# Asp.net webform device responsive

Tags: asp.net, responsive-design, webforms

I have a requirement to make one of my existing websites device responsive. The website was developed using ASP.NET webforms. I am not allowed to use frameworks like BootStrap or Foundation. My company has a team who develops styles. Can I assume that the responsiveness can be achieved with just these styles? Webforms use server controls, does it create an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is "just CSS". There's nothing special about it as far as the browser is concerned. Therefore, you can do what Bootstrap does. And server controls can have CSS applied to them. So yes, you can create a responsive site with your own CSS in a Web Forms application.

Answer (score 0):

> responsiveness can be achieved with just these styles?

Responsive design is having styles for each device resolution, normally: small, medium, desktop, and big desktop.

> Webforms use server controls, does it create an issue?

As long as you have them with a good set of CSS classes hierarchy, everything is made really easy for the "team who develops styles"

---

Responsive design **is not about the server technology**, it's mostly about **CSS Styling**, though in some particular cases, a good HTML set makes things easier to tweak around, one of the examples is having a nice responsive `<table>` where the left column is fixed and the rest will "slide"... It's accomplish with only CSS but a good table with good class names makes things really easy.